# What is wrong with this backbone router?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Yes I have included undescore library and I now bind my loadChisiamo but I still got this issue.This is main.js

```
app_start();

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "home" : "loadHome",
      "chisiamo" : "loadChisiamo",
      "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this,'loadHome','loadChisiamo');
    },
    loadHome: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('loadHome');
      var home = new home_view();
    },
    loadChisiamo: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('loadChisiamo');
      var chiSiamo = new chiSiamo_view();
    },
    defaultRoute: function(actions) {
    }
  });

  var app_router;
  function app_start(){
    views();

    var topBar = new topbar_view();
    var menu = new menu_view();
    var home = new home_view();
    //app_router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });

    topBar.render();
    menu.render();
    home.render();
  }

  var topbar_view,, menu_view,  home_view, chiSiamo_view;
  function views() {
    topbar_view = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#header',
      template: Handlebars.templates['topbarHome.ht'],
      initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
      },
      render : function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
      }
    });
    menu_view = Backbone.View.extend({...});
    home_view = Backbone.View.extend({...});
    chiSiamo_view = Backbone.View.extend({...});
  }
```

Now, once I uncomment app_router = new Router() I get this error 'undefined is not a function '. So it's like I didnt define my router but I did above. So what can be the problem? This is my index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id='header' class="header"></div>
        <div id='main' class="main">
            <div id="navigation"></div>
            <div id="contain"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendor/plugins/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/templates.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It is looking for underscore to be loaded.  Are you including that library in your environment?

Comment: _.bindAll(this,'loadHome', 'loadChisiamo'); Underscore is trying to bind 'loadHome' and 'loadChisiamo' methods, but it can't find 'loadChisiamo'. Use non-minified version of underscore and break the debugger on exception so you can inspect the cause of the undefined.